# One Custom B2B App for Multiple Clients

Tags: ios, ipad, project, target

I have written a custom B2B app for a SMB Accounting Software that is modifiable. The main source code that I wrote is compatible only for the generic, unmodified desktop version of the software. That main source code will then be modified to match the modifications each client has on their desktop software.

Now, my question is what do you see the best way is to keep track of all of these different modifications and different clients.

1. Duplicate the unmodified source code for each client, then fix any bugs/upgrades in the main source code in each clients project.
2. Keep one code base with multiple targets and write if statements for each modification to check the current target. Fix any bugs/upgrades in one place. (Currently doing this.)

Do you see any other options than the two that I posted above? The one potential problem I see with number 2 is scaleability. If we get too many mods in one project it may get too crowded. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar business model.  I simply keep different branches of the same code base.

1. Put main code base into SCC and call it Master (or whatever) - I use Git
2. Create new branch for each company (Branch - Company X)
3. Make custom modifications to the new branch (Branch - Company X)
4. If I'm making changes that affect all branches, make those changes in the main branch (Master)